# UItableview inside Uitableview cell, inner uitableview doesn't show up

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to add a UItableview inside Uitableview cell but inner uitableview doesn't show up. The outer tableview has tag 100 and the inner tag 90. I am not sure why only the outer table view is displayed and the code never reaches to have tag 90. Can you please advise? I been stuck with this for days. Please find the code below. Thank you !

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController ,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView.tag == 100 {
            return 10
        } else {
            return 3
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if tableView.tag == 100 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainTableViewCell") as! MainTableViewCell
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InsideTableViewCell") as! InsideTableViewCell
            return cell
        }
    }
}

import UIKit

class MainTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var lblName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var tblInsideTableView: UITableView!

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}

extension MainTableViewCell {
    func setTableViewDataSourceDelegate
        <D:UITableViewDelegate & UITableViewDataSource>
        (_ dataSourceDelegate: D, forRow row: Int)
    {
        tblInsideTableView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
        tblInsideTableView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate

        tblInsideTableView.reloadData()
    }
}


import UIKit

class InsideTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var lblInsideName: UILabel!

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

Comment: Where have you assigned datasource and delegate of innerTableView to UIViewController ?

Comment: Where do you call your `setTableViewDataSourceDelegate` function?

Comment: @rmaddy I don't, how do you suggest I do that?

Comment: @Anuraj I connected datasource and delegate to the tableview of each uitableview

Comment: You should call it from `cellForRowAt` in `ViewController`.

Comment: @Bubu You have implemented data source and delegate  in the ViewController. So set the both the delegate and datasource of both tableviews to the ViewController class.

Comment: @rmaddy can you give me an example on how to do that? thanks

Comment: @Anuraj can you please give me an example on how to do that? thanks!!

Comment: i think its not a good practice placing tableView inside every tableViewCell. Even if you do, your will face another challenge, that is you should make every main cell's height fit to your inner tableView content.

Comment: @mnemonic23 what do you suggest as an alternative? I wanna have list (the outer table)and a sublist (inner table)of variable length thanks

Comment: i recommend using tableView section. Each section represent inner tableView.